# Is there a way to verify using liquid, if script tag is duplicated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, liquid

I would like to check using liquid language, if is there somewhere in the page, a script being called twice or more.
For example:

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

Is it possible using liquid or should I use javascript to validate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about liquid, but if you wanted to go the JS route, this could work:

```js
//locate all `<script>` tags and save the elements into an array
var scriptTags = [];
document.querySelectorAll('script').forEach(function(tag) {
  scriptTags.push(tag)
});

//Put just the URLs of the script tags into an array
var scriptUrls = scriptTags.map(function(tag) {
  return tag.src;
});

//Get a list of any URL that appears more than once
var duplicateUrls = scriptUrls.filter(function(url, i) {
  return scriptUrls.indexOf(url) != i;
});

console.log(duplicateUrls);
```

```html
<script src="dupe.js"></script>
<script src="other1.js"></script>
<script src="dupe.js"></script>
<script src="other2.js"></script>
<script src="other3.js"></script>
```